How can we use angular material UI in angular 17
If there is no app.module.ts file so how can we user angular material , because for using angular material first we need to import material module, is there any another way to do it ?
I tried to import it inside config file but it's now worked

So basically the thing is, Angular v-17 onwards standalone is default via CLI ,which means when you create new project it wont have any modules in it. Either you can create a project using --no-standalone flag i.e ng new project --no-standalone or else you can import dependencies into the component instead of app.modules,like the code below:


import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
@Component({
  standalone:true,
  imports: [
     MatAutocompleteModule,
   ],
   selector: 'your-component',
   templateUrl: './your.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./your.component.scss']
 })



Hope this helps!!
